# Время отображения пуш уведомления на рабочем столе

Tags: веб-программирование, firebase, push

Прикрутили к сайту систему вебпуш-уведомлений через google firebase сервис
https://habrahabr.ru/post/321924/
все отлично работает, кроме того, что уведомление когда приходит на рабочий стол, то исчезает через 15 секунд само и если пользователь отходил от компа то он его соответственно и не увидит
Может кто подсказать пожалуйста как настроить какой параметр в js файле, исполняющего роль worker.js, чтобы сообщение висело дольше на рабочем столе или вообще не исчезало пока пользователь на него не отреагирует?

Comment: разве это не настраивается непосредственно в сервисе, которое производит рассылку?

Comment: в гугловском сервисе не нашли мы ничего такого ((